# How to replace rows based on this condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I would like to know how to make this thing:
e.g. row `'AMG 1.4 oil'` starts with `'AMG'`, I need to make it only `'AMG'`. If it does not start with `'AMG'`, it should not be changed.

Can you please advise me on how to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.my_col.str.startswith('AMG'),'my_col'] = 'AMG'
```

Answer (score 1):

`list-comprehension` can be used to rename a single column.
As following

```
df.columns = ['AMG' if 'AMG' in x else x for x in df.columns]
```

Comment: The questions was regarding the data, not the columns...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'row': {0: 'AMG 1.4 oil', 1: 'MG 1.4 oil', 2: '1.4 oil', 3: 'oil'}})

df['row'].apply(lambda x : 'AMG' if x[:3]=='AMG' else x)
```

output:

```
0           AMG
1    MG 1.4 oil
2       1.4 oil
3           oil
Name: row, dtype: object
```

Comment: @hirolau, thanks, I edit the code block, is this correct?